# understanding the factorisation machine formula

Tags: matrix-factorisation, field-aware-factorization-machines

I am reading [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/factorization-machines-for-item-recommendation-with-implicit-feedback-data-5655a7c749db#:%7E:text=Factorization%20Machines%20(FM)%20are%20generic,regression%2C%20classification%2C%20and%20ranking.) about factorisation machines.

I get the intuition behind it, compute the dot product between the (user/item)+(item/aux features)+(user/aux features). This dot product can impact y_hat.

But I don't understand the formula below. I understand the first section, the bias. I understand the second section, first order weighting.

But I don't understand the last section.

I understand the `<v,v>`, this could be dot product of `<user,item>` or `<item, aux feature>`.
But what are the x's? Would these be scalar values?

Also can someone just confirm that $P$ would be 3 in my example as that is users, items and aux features.

[image]